# How to link in panel four pic to one. Only winForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to make 4 different images in one, and it will be in the panel. Panel size will vary from 180 to 320. I tried to do one main panel, and in her place 4, which are fixed by anchors.. but it turns out sucks

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel main_panel = new Panel();
    main_panel.BackColor = Color.Azure;
    Panel panel_top_left = new Panel();
    Panel panel_top_right = new Panel();
    Panel panel_bottom_left = new Panel();
    Panel panel_bottom_right = new Panel();

    Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_l);
    panel_top_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_left;
    Bitmap btm_msg_panel_top_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_t_r);
    panel_top_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_top_right;
    Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_left = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_b_l);
    panel_bottom_left.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_left;
    Bitmap btm_msg_panel_bottom_right = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.blue_b_r);
    panel_bottom_right.BackgroundImage = btm_msg_panel_bottom_right;

    main_panel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
    panel_top_left.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
    panel_top_right.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left;
    panel_bottom_left.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left;
    panel_bottom_right.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;

    main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_top_left);
    main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_top_right);
    main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_left);
    main_panel.Controls.Add(panel_bottom_right);

    panel1.Controls.Add(main_panel);
}
```

This is source of 4 pics

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I try to get them like this

[image]

Comment: how does it suck? Could you be more elaborate? I think some screen shot showing *how it sucks* would be better.

Comment: So how should it look?

Comment: also i tried make one pic in photoshop... :) but this is not good...

Comment: You want to place 4 panel in one but why you are using anchor property ? i think you must code position of that four panel and anchor property will not do that, i guess.

Comment: i use anchor because this panel is flexible in width. If you will use position, i guess you know what will be...

Comment: Holding shift in Paint let's you draw straight lines. Just saying.

Comment: @Andrius Naruševičius ok...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I just use **tableLayoutPanel** instead of **Panel** i hope it will help you.
 Code for this is as below.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableLayoutPanel myTable = new TableLayoutPanel();
        myTable.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        myTable.Size = new Size(506, 417);
        myTable.AutoSize = true;
        myTable.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        myTable.GrowStyle = System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.AddRows;
        myTable.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
        this.Controls.Add(myTable);

        Panel panel1 = new Panel();
        Panel panel2 = new Panel();
        Panel panel3 = new Panel();
        Panel panel4 = new Panel();

        panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;          
        panel2.BackColor = Color.Black;           
        panel3.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        panel4.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

        myTable.Controls.Add(panel1, 0, 0);
        myTable.Controls.Add(panel2, 0, 1);
        myTable.Controls.Add(panel3, 0, 2);
        myTable.Controls.Add(panel4, 0, 3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess `Zuhan` doesn't have enough reputation to `vote up`, he could have had enough but there were some questions receiving too many down-votes.

Comment: one more question, if tableLayoutPanel create dynamically, how to set borders, on needs position???

Comment: @King King, i just start to learn WinForms, and have a lot of questions... so i ask... Is not bad :)

Comment: Let me first add code which will add as many control as you want, (add table dynamically)

Comment: Yes, please! Panels and tableLayoutPanel create dynamically

Comment: @Zuhan borders, on needs position??? you can set border to panel on which you need and do not set border to table simple :)

Comment: panel1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle; It will set border on panel

Comment: Listen, I need to get a picture, four to one. what you showed me - just confusing. Look at the top of that I need to get

Comment: What i show you is how to add panel in order, because you know how to get bitmap image from resource you also code for that. i don't have images that's why added colors.